# GET параметры в Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Есть маршрут, по которому открывается главная страница

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

Можно как-то получить GET параметр без создания контроллера? То есть будет example.com/?id=1, как получить этот id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
Route::get('/', function (Request $req) { 
    $req->query('id'); 
    ... 
});
```

Больше информации [тут](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input-from-the-query-string)

Comment: Да можно просто `$req->id` – тоже отдаст параметр

Answer (score 0):

Ещё есть удобный хелпер `request()`.

Пример для `example.com/?param=45`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if(request()->filled('param')){
        $param = request('param');
        dd($param);
    }
});
```